# Build Pyomo Sets into a Python dictionnary

Tags: python, anaconda, python-3.5, linear-programming, pyomo

For example, I want to create a dictionnary of Pyomo Sets from a Python dictionnary of lists named `dictOfList`. `dictOfList` is built as follow:

```
dictOfList= {}
dictOfList[1] = [10,11,12]
dictOfList[2] = [20,21]
dictOfList[3] = [31,32,33,34]
```

Now, I would like the values `[10,11,12]`, `[20,21]`, and `[31,32,33,34]` to be put in a Python dictionnary of Pyomo Sets named `dictOfSets` as follow:

```
model.dictOfSets = {}
for el in dictOfList:
    model.dictOfSets[el] = Set(initialize=dictOfList[el])
```

Then, if I display the values of the Sets using another simple for loop:

```
for el in dictOfList:
    model.dictOfSets[el].display()
```

It seems like the Sets are not properly built, since it shows this in the running console:

```
_unknown_ : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed
_unknown_ : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed
_unknown_ : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=0, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
    Not constructed
```

Is there a way to build a Pyomo Set *inside* a Python dictionnary? Right now, I have used normal Python lists, but it caused me very long processing time in larger models, and I know that it is better to use Pyomo Sets for faster performances in building constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Set`s are not being fully constructed because they are never being assigned to a `Block` or model object.  While not exactly what you are asking for (you don't actually end up with a `dict` of `Set`s on your model), the easiest thing to do to get the effect you want is to actually create an *indexed* `Set`:

```
dictOfList= {}
dictOfList[1] = [10,11,12]
dictOfList[2] = [20,21]
dictOfList[3] = [31,32,33,34]
model.S = Set(dictOfList.keys(), initialize=dictOfList)
```

If you print the model (`model.pprint()`), you will get:

```
2 Set Declarations
    S : Dim=1, Dimen=1, Size=9, Domain=None, ArraySize=3, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Key : Members
          1 : [10, 11, 12]
          2 : [20, 21]
          3 : [31, 32, 33, 34]
    S_index : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(1, 3)
        [1, 2, 3]
```

To actually create a Python `dict` of `Set`s you would also need to assign each individual `Set` to the model so that it gets properly constructed.  Something like this could work:

```
model.dictOfSets = {}
for el in dictOfList:
    model.dictOfSets[el] = Set(initialize=dictOfList[el])
    setattr(model, 'dictOfSets_member_%s' % (el,), model.dictOfSets[el])
for el in dictOfList:
    model.dictOfSets[el].display()
```

gives

```
dictOfSets_member_1 : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(10, 12)
    [10, 11, 12]
dictOfSets_member_2 : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=2, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(20, 21)
    [20, 21]
dictOfSets_member_3 : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=4, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(31, 34)
    [31, 32, 33, 34]
```

---

**EDIT:** You can have more complicated indexing if you explicitly create the indexed `Set`'s index.  That is:

```
model.S_IDX = Set(initialize=dictOfList.keys())
model.S = Set(model.S_IDX, initialize=dictOfList)
```

By explicitly creating the set, you can have arbitrarily complicated keys.  Note that in some cases you may have to explicitly set the "dimension" of the index Set using the `dimen=` keyword:

```
dictOfList = { (1,2): [10,11,12],
               (2,3): [20,21],
               (1,3): [31,32,33,34],
}
model.S_IDX = Set(initialize=dictOfList.keys(), dimen=2)
model.S = Set(model.S_IDX, initialize=dictOfList)
```

This is especially true if you want the tuples to have different lengths:

```
dictOfList = { (1,): [10,11,12],
               (2,3): [20,21],
               (1,3,4): [31,32,33,34],
}
model.S_IDX = Set(initialize=dictOfList.keys(), dimen=None)
model.S = Set(model.S_IDX, initialize=dictOfList)
```

Where `model.pprint()` gives:

```
2 Set Declarations
    S : Dim=None, Dimen=1, Size=9, Domain=None, ArraySize=3, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Key       : Members
             (1,) : [10, 11, 12]
        (1, 3, 4) : [31, 32, 33, 34]
           (2, 3) : [20, 21]
    S_IDX : Dim=0, Dimen=None, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        [(1,), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: As you said, using the line `model.S = Set(dictOfList.keys(), initialize=dictOfList)` worked. I also like how you linked the Set to the model, that was going to be my next question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I have got an harder one: What if we have a case where dictionnary keys are tuples?

Comment: If they are all the same length, then explicitly create the S_index set.  I will update the answer so that we can get reasonable formatting.